# Deleting entry from map shows leak in Valgrind

Tags: c++, dictionary, valgrind, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

char a[10];
map <string, char*> mm;

void update(string s, char* b)
{
    delete mm[s];
    mm[s] = b;
}
int main()
{ 
    char* ptr = new char[100];
    char* ptr1 = new char[100];
    mm.insert(pair<string, char*>(string("abc"), ptr));
    update ("abc", ptr1);  

    delete ptr1;
    return 0; 
 }
```

My code is somewhat like this. When I tried to delete the value using the key , Valgrind shows a leak.

```
 delete mymap[key];
```

But I tried the above code same Valgrind shows no leak. Is there any disadvantage there for using delete in the map like this? I assigned an iterator and tried to delete it using that like

```
delete itr->second;
```

and it is working fine. No Leak. What is the problem with the first way of delete?

Comment: Why are you raw pointers at all?

Comment: You're not calling the right form of delete.  It should be `delete []`, not `delete`.  Also why would you write code like this on purpose?  Why not simply `map<string, string>`?

Comment: I hope that this is just a toy code for learning purpose & not using `char*` in production. Otherwise, `delete ptr1` may cause undefined behavior, if `mm` is used after it. BTW, `delete mymap[key];` is tricky in general, because if no `key` exists then you are deleting nothing. It's always better to go with iterators. Also as mentioned by @Paul, you should be calling `delete[]` for arrays.

Comment: The other mistake is that you're including the wrong header.  The header is `<string>`, not `<string.h>`.

Comment: Does the code you posted **here** exhibit the "leak" you claim you're having? Being "somewhat like this", beyond identifying of your incorrect usage of `delete` vs `delete[]`, is otherwise worthless if it doesn't experience similar behavior.

Comment: It's just a toy code, in production, it is the string and passing a string value. I'm just using this code for illustration purpose.

Comment: This code does not have any leak, but my product code is similar to this and its shows leak. When I tried to find out the leak, it shows that the leak is in the delete line. I changed it and use an iterator to delete it. Now it is not showing any leak

Answer (score 1):

There are following problems with your code:

1. Mingling with `char*` when you have clearly a choice to use
   `std::string`
2. With `std::map` it's always tricky to use `operator[]` as you are
   doing in `delete mm[s];`, if key = `s` doesn't exist then you are
   deleting nothing
3. Because you are creating array with `new[]`, you must use
   `delete[]`. Otherwise it's undefined behavior.
4. The `delete ptr1` in the end is dangerous, because if `mm` is used
   afterwards then you are accessing a dangling pointer.

To answer your Q, I am not sure why Valgrind shows memory leak, because technically you are on "undefined behavior".

I would recommend to use:

```
map <string, string> mm;
```

or

```
map <string, std::unique_ptr<char[]>> mm;
```

Comment: Point 4:  In the sample code, `mm` *is* used afterwards - it's destructor is called.  You'd have to do some rather careful language lawyering to determine if that is enough to invoke UB, or whether the invalid pointer in the map is never touched by the maps destructor.

Comment: @MartinBonner, I feel that calling a destructor on pointer will result in NOp (No Operation), hence still it should be fine. In above case, apparently it's not being used, so still it's ok. However in real code, such deletion doesn't happen and if it happens then the corresponding map element also should be erased.

Comment: Point 2: There is nothing wrong with "deleting nothing". It may indicate a bug though that it is being attempted.

Comment: I am unit testing the code so there is a value in the table always. The second part is not  character pointer, it is a pointer to the object. For illustration purpose, I used the `char*`